# Styling a textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textarea, styling

I'm absolutely new to JavaScript and would like to modify a textarea of a form (which is generated by an external script) as follows:

1.) Textarea on start: Labeled 'Your message here' in color 'rgb(136, 136, 136)'

2.) Textarea on focus: Label removed and color set to 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'

3.) Textarea on blur: Color of user input set to 'rgb(136, 136, 136)'; if there's no input, label reappears in color 'rgb(136, 136, 136)'

I've experimented around with

```
var foo = document.getElementById('HCB_textarea');
foo.innerHTML = 'Your message here';
foo.style.color = 'rgb(136, 136, 136)';
foo.onfocus = do something;
foo.onblur = do something;
```

but didn't get it right. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming by 'label' you don't mean a label HTML element, but instead default text in the textrea as your example seems to suggest, try this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('HCB_textarea');
var defaultText = 'Your message here';
foo.value = defaultText;
foo.style.color = '#888';
foo.onfocus = function(){
    foo.style.color = '#000';
    if ( foo.value == defaultText ) {
        foo.value = '';
    }
};
foo.onblur = function(){
    foo.style.color = '#888';
    if ( foo.value == '' ) {
        foo.value = defaultText;
    }

};
```

Comment: Avoid setting `innerHTML` on `<textarea>`. It's not supposed to set the value of the field. (In practice, it does, but only sometimes, and unreliably across different browsers.) Use `value`.

Comment: Hi Mario! This seems to work perfectly except one little thing: The defaultText does not reappear if there has been some user input before which got removed again.

Comment: As bobince suggested it would be better to use 'value' instead of 'innerHTML'. So, can I simply replace it ('foo.value = defaultText;')?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine, I'll change it in this post too

Comment: Replacing 'innerHTML' by 'value' works like a charm and also solved the issue with the non-reappearing defaultText. Thanks a billion, Mario and bradlis7, you've just made my day!!

Answer (score 1):

That looks pretty close to me. You have to color all or none of the textarea, you can't color certain characters without some crazy hacks.

```
var foo = document.getElementById('HCB_textarea');
var labelVal = 'Your message here'
foo.value = origVal;
foo.style.color = 'rgb(136, 136, 136)';
foo.onfocus = function() {
  if( foo.value == labelVal ) foo.value = "";
  foo.style.color = 'rgb(136, 136, 136)';
}
foo.onblur = function() {
  if( foo.value != "" ) {
    foo.style.color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
  } else {
    foo.value = labelVal;
    foo.style.color = 'rgb(136, 136, 136)';
  }
}
// You should modify this to use your actual form name.
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
  if( foo.value == labelVal ) foo.value = "";
}
```

---

**EDIT** - I modified the code because Mario pointed out that you meant you wanted the label to be inside of the textarea, not a `<label>` element.