# JavaScript: 'textarea.value' not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

A few hours ago, I was instructed [how to style a specific textarea with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630378/styling-a-textarea-with-javascript). The following piece of code (thanks again, Mario Menger) works like a charm in Firefox but unfortunately nothing happens in Internet Explorer (7 tested only so far).

```
var foo = document.getElementById('HCB_textarea');
var defaultText = 'Your message here';
foo.value = defaultText;
foo.style.color = '#888';
foo.onfocus = function(){
    foo.style.color = '#000';
    if ( foo.value == defaultText ) {
        foo.value = '';
    }
};
foo.onblur = function(){
    foo.style.color = '#888';
    if ( foo.value == '' ) {
        foo.value = defaultText;
    }

};
```

I've already tried to replace 'value' by 'innerHTML' (for IE only) but to no effect. Any suggestions? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. Full non-working test-case?

If you are running the page from local filesystem, make sure to allow JavaScript to run, either through the infobar, enabling ‘Allow active content to run in files on My Computer’, or adding the ‘Mark of the Web’.

You might also want to make it go grey only in the empty/defaultText case.

Edit: OK, that is one seriously vile page eBay are spitting out there, full of crazy broken content and shonky scripts. It has an `ErrorHandlerManager` thing that stops your problem getting reported, as well as some other script errors on the page. Nice.

Bizarrely, eBay seem to be serving it to IE as complicated nested iframes, where Firefox gets it all on one document. Either this or the bizarre way the ‘htmlcommentbox’ script is being loaded causes your watermark script following it to be run before the comment box has been appended to the page, causing the attempt to `getElementById` to fail.

I put a `window.onload= function() { ... }` wrapper around your script and that made it work. I don't know if it might interfere with anything else on the page potentially using the `window.onload` event though (there's too much unpleasant broken scripting to go through to check), but if so there's always `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your efforts, bobince (like your website by the way *g*). Did you put the mentioned wrapper around the whole script (HTML comment box + watermark) or watermark only? Could I realize this for IE only (via Conditional Comments)? What do you mean saying "there's always addEventListener/attachEvent". And for clarification: The page resp. template is forced into these nested (nasty! *g*) iframes when refreshed once. I use another script to trigger this "embedding" right from the first load for IE only because of CSS issues.

Comment: What I really want to say is that the watermark script works perfectly in FF even if the iframe construction comes in... ;-)

Comment: I just put it around the watermark addition. This gave the external htmlcommentbox script time to load; in IE it was not loading synchronously like in Firefox. I'm not wholly sure it's guaranteed that a DOM-inserted script element will delay onload until it is finished, though... you might also try losing the hcb script loader and just `document.write`​ing the script tag instead.

Comment: `window.onload = function() { ... }` did it! You're a genius, bobince! Thanks a lot and Gn8

Answer (score 1):

If your script is at the top of the page, it's likely that it is running before the page has fully loaded. So the element you are trying to reference doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I've pasted the script mentioned here right below the main script; the form resp. the HTML is created by JS as well.

Answer (score 1):

Internet explorer, javascript and markup just don't fit in one sentence unfortunately. Always a pain to script for it.

Anyway to debug you might try if the events get called by putting `alert("onblur works!");` like lines in. Maybe alert with the value of some variables you are testing or changing.

Comment: Yep, as you expected there's no alert in IE but in FF, so I'll test every event separately.

Comment: That's why we use frameworks like jQuery. They've already figured out the vast majority of the IE v.s. FF issues already.